# Making multivalue input script run from Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, python-script-tool, multi-values

I have a working python script:

```
import arcpy

sdeconnection = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
layerfiles = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1).split(";")

for layerfile in layerfiles:
    print layerfile
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layerfile)
    lyr.replaceDataSource(sdeconnection, "SDE_WORKSPACE", lyr.datasetName, False)
    lyr.save()
    del lyr
```

I can run it from the command line with multiple layer files as input (separated by ";").

However I cannot make it work when I the script to add to a toolbox. The script runs as expected if I set "multivalue" to false for the layerfiles parameter.

[image: parameters settings]

However when I set "multivalue" to true I get the error:

```
Start Time: Thu May 16 10:13:47 2013
Running script changeLyrWorkspace...
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source
Failed to execute (changeLyrWorkspace).
Failed at Thu May 16 10:13:47 2013 (Elapsed Time: 0,00 seconds)
```

I get this error regardless of whether I add one or more layers when I run the script through the toolbox.

**EDIT**

It turns out that the script works through the GUI *if* there are no spaces in file name of the layer file.

Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Add an arcpy.AddMessage("file " + layerfile) after the print layer file, and compare to the results of the print statement

Answer (score 3):

The multivalue parameter mechanism adds single quotes around parameter values that contain spaces. (This is somewhat vaguely described in the arcpy `ValueTable` documentation.) So for instance a parameter with spaces will be:

```
'two words';oneword
```

instead of (as you might expect):

```
two words;oneword
```

You can strip off any enclosing single quotes with the `strip` method:

```
values = [v.strip("'") for v in parameters[0].valueAsText.split(';')]
```

You could also access the underlying ValueTable in the parameter directly.